# Moderator diamonds (♦) should not be underlined in comments

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Everywhere else only the handle of moderators is underlined, whereas the ♦ is not. In comments, instead...

[image: diamond]

I don't think this is correct.

Comment: comment to test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be resolved on dev and should go out in the build. Thanks.